# Conditionally Average Values In Multiple Columns

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with results from a single horse across multiple horse races, formatted as follows:

```
    1000m          1200m
Place    Gate   Place   Gate
3        5      8       10
1        8      2       12
```

and so on. I would like to collect data on whether the horse performs better from certain gates. So I have the following table that I want to populate:

```
                    Gate    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
Average position by gate
```

So for each "Place" column, I need to search for cells where the "Gate" column reads 1,2,3, etc, and then average these values. How can I achieve this? I have tried AVERAGEIF, but I can only use this on one distance at a time. I need a way to do this across all of the "Place" and "Gate" columns.

Comment: You should show us the desired result based on your example. Also, if the distance (1000m and 1200m) does not matter, why don't you put all data into 2 columns (Place and Gate) and use AVERAGEIFS in another result table?

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach if you have the newest version of Excel:

```
=IFERROR(FIXED(LET(gate, TEXTJOIN(",", 1,$B$3:$B$10,$D$3:$D$10,$F$3:$F$10),
place, TEXTJOIN(",", 1, $A$3:$A$10,$C$3:$C$10,$E$3:$E$10),
x, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(gate, ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
y, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(place, ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
AVERAGE(FILTER(y, x=A13)))),"")
```

[image]

The solution relies on the `LET` function. First, we join the gate (place) data together into a single string disregarding distance using `TEXTJOIN`. Next we append this data together into a dynamic array with `FILTERXML`. Finally, we `FILTER` the array of places to only those which occurred with a given gate position and average them. For best practice, we wrap the entire function in an `IFERROR` and format our result to display two decimals with `FIXED`.

I am sure someone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you could do:

```
=LET( matrix, A3:F17,
       gates, SEQUENCE(1,12),
       rdC, COLUMNS( matrix ), rdCells, ROWS( matrix ) * rdC,
       rdIR, SEQUENCE( 1, rdCells, 0 ),
       wrR, ROUNDUP( rdCells/2, 0),  wrCells, wrR * 2,
       wrIR, SEQUENCE( wrR, 2, 0 ),
       mux, INDEX( matrix, rdIR/rdC + 1, MOD( rdIR, rdC ) + 1 ),
       demux, INDEX( mux, wrIR/wrCells +  1,  MOD( wrIR, wrCells ) + 1 ),
       m, (INDEX(demux,,2)=gates)*INDEX(demux,,1),
       ones, SIGN( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( m ) ) ),
       CHOOSE( {1;2}, gates, IFERROR( MMULT( ones, m ) / MMULT( ones, SIGN(m) ), "") )
     )
```

where **matrix** is the range of *Place* and *Gate* columns to be analyzed.

[image: result]

The first several lines are designed to reshape the matrix into two columns of Place and Gate called **demux** (I reused a formula that I wrote for reshaping arrays, so the **mux** and **demux** are designed to multiplex **matrix** into a single row and then demultiplex it into the desired new shape of paired columns).

**m** picks up **demux** and turns it into a ***races** X **gates*** matrix with results (where no-result = 0). **ones** is used to create a summation of each column via MMULT which will be divided by the count of each column to create an average:

```
MMULT( ones, m ) / MMULT( ones, SIGN(m) )
```

This is wrapped in an IFERROR to replace the div/0 errors with "" - *you can change that to what you want it to be - perhaps you want it to be div/0 because that is what AVERAGE would deliver anyway*.

The CHOOSE just stitches the result together in the form that you presented in your question.

Comment: This approach is based on using an Excel Formula, but Power BI could be more interesting. This would allow the Distance to be treated as data as well and would allow for correlations of position and gate with distance.